# Dot net core web api: Where to put models used in multiple APIs

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My new hobby project is based on https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers. Trying my best to learn about how to write an enterprise microservice web application.

In Microsoft's example you will find a `Model` folder in each `*.API` project containing models. These models are only ever used in their respective project e.g:

```
eShopOnContainers/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Model/BasketItem.cs
eShopOnContainers/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Model/CatalogType.cs
```

In my example I have some models that are used in two or even three different APIs. Where would I put them according to the eShopOnContainers example?

The simplest example would be an `enum` used by multiple APIs.

Comment: You can make a simple class library with all the shared components in it. Add a reference to that library in all projects.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do that. My question is more related to "WHERE to put that library in this existing structure".

Comment: a true microservice does not share.

Comment: @MarkusDresch I am creating a sports application and have a Team.API and a Player.API. Both use a Position enum. A player has a position and a team has a formation with positions. Does this mean I should duplicate the enum for both services?

Comment: probably yes. or maybe even a position microservice, depends on your design. in microservice world forget all you have learned about reusing code. robustness comes from not having any hard dependencies.

Comment: in case you do create a shared library, you'd have to treat it like any external library. in the end updating every single microservice to a new version of your model is not any more fun than copying code around. also, your models most probably are not the same in every service, otherwise you might have to rethink your domain boundaries.

Comment: Thank you! If you like you can use this as answer and I will mark it!

Comment: If you take a closer look at eShopOnContainers, you'll see that BasketItem (for example) *does* exist in multiple projects. It is defined in the Basket.API project, the Ordering.API project, and the WebMVC project. The properties are exactly the same (although the one in Basket.API also includes a Validate method). Rather than using a single, canonical class that is shared across these three projects, each project uses only its own class definition of the (mostly) identical object. A shared definition would couple these projects together in a way that microservice architectures try to avoid.